# libGDX поворот текстуры

Tags: java, libgdx

Пытаюсь рисовать линию с помощью SpriteBatch
Беру картинку размером 1х1, растягиваю её до нужных размеров и отрисовываю
Таким способом могу рисовать вертикальную и горизонтальную линию, но как мне её рисовать под углом?

```
// горизонтальная
batchLight.draw(piece,p.x,p.y+p.radius,p.x2-p.radius-p.radius,-6);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Используй [Sprite](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) вместо текстуры.
2) установи центр спрайта
3) вращай.

```
sprite.setOriginCenter();
sprite.rotate(float degrees);
sprite.draw(batch);
```

А вообще лучше использовать [ShapeRanderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html), где можно рисовать линии, прямоугольники, круги, полигоны, etc...